# список перевести в список int( 1,2,3 ...)

Tags: python, список

есть список array
[<Cell R27C1 'string'>, <Cell R28C1 'string'>, <Cell R29C1 'string'>]

делаю так

```py
array = list(map(int, list))
print(array)
```

сообщение
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Cell'

Comment: если `Cell` это ваш класс, то реализуйте метод `__init__`

Comment: А каким образом __init__ поможет?)

Comment: Это вряд ли класс, судя по его представлению.

Comment: в вопросе не хватает __воспроизводимого__ примера...

Comment: работаю с gspread, CELL - ячейки таблицы. ответы приходят отсюда - sheet.findall(message.text)

Answer (score 0):

Если у этой сущности `Cell` есть какой-то метод получить его значение в виде строки, то используйте его прежде чем скармливать элементы списка функции `map()`.

```
array = list(map(lambda el: int(el.value), list))
```